# How to access input fields in a page from a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a Chrome extension for personal use that makes all the password fields `type="text"`, so I can see the clear passwords. (I know that I can probably find something like this in the Chrome store, but it's something I want to do myself).

I am however having a hard time accessing the actual page content (the page I'm viewing in the tab). If I do

```
document.getElementById('text')
```

this selects the element from `background.html` not the page I'm viewing. How can I access the actual page?

Also, is there a way I can include an external javascript file so I can use functions from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use [content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/content_scripts.html) - javascript file injected into an actual page with access to DOM and events.